# How do i make list of files executable at once in git bash?

Tags: git-bash

I want to make all files executable in a folder, and instead of doing it separately, is there a command that i can make all the files executable all at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goto the directory and execute `chmod +x ./*`.

This command will makes all files under current directory to executable, the `*` is one of the standard wildcard, if you want to checkout all standard wildcards and its usage, [view in here](https://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm).

Comment: it didn't make them executable, I am using git bash. Is that a problem?

Comment: What OS environment you are using?

Comment: I am using windows 10.....But thanks i figured it out. It was git add --chmod=+x  ./*

Comment: Not recommended. this will change a normal file to executable permission as well.

Answer (score 1):

navigate to the directory you wish to make its files executable and run
`git add --chmod=+x ./*`
then git add, commit and push as normal.
(this is how I do mine)